# Multi row dependent dropdown

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm currently working on adding a dependent drop down to a spreadsheet I'm working on. I've used this formula to create a working dependent drop down on one row...

```
=if(J9=Operators!B1,indirect("Operator"),if(J9=Operators!C1,indirect("Livery")))
```

....but I wish for this to be replicated in each row down to `J65`. I've played around with my formula to no avail and have also made use of an array/transpose formula which I found via a google search but this only creates an error message asking me to add 700 more columns

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: If I have done this right a link to my actual spreadsheet titled 'EMU' should be here....[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEIvSB7wwoxSolxrn2G12jfx5APFi5P8w1CxYrzQvWQ/edit?usp=sharing [link] 

On this my issue relates to J and L columns of '390' tab where I require the selection in J to reflect the options available in L. Where 'livery' is selected in J, L should show the list from the C column of the 'Operators' tab and where 'Operator' is shown in J column, the L column should show list from B column of 'Operators' tab. The formula I have attempted is shown in A71 of '390' tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need arrayformula like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(J9:J65="Livery", 
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Operators!B2:B, Operators!B2:B<>"")), IF(J9:J65="Operator", 
 TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Operators!C2:C, Operators!C2:C<>"")), ))))
```

which will generate the items for dropdown and then you need to create a dropdown per each cell in L column

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo for first 3 dropdowns in L column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A-lzK5gNtiCeU_1KDPpvYrDx1x2HJhpMIimM6RyZQDU/copy)

Comment: That formula is perfect! You will notice that the J & L columns are repeated in columns O&P and S&T so can I incorporate these columns into the same formula to keep things tidy? To give you an example of what I'm referring to, once this spreadsheet is completed there will be operator amendments in J9:J65 and livery amendments in O9:O65 so can the same formula that works on the J column also work for the O column?

Comment: unfortunately, no. for O&P and S&T you will need a separate formula for each because if you choose in J value "Livery" then you need the freedom to select in O value different than "Livery"

Comment: I suspected that would be the case but had hoped there might have been an and/or type formula. It does create another issue as both the livery and operator columns in the 'operators' tab will require adding to as the spreadsheet develops. Is there anyway of getting columns to add automatically where the arrayformula is or will I need to try and plan ahead and leave a suitable gap between the 2 formulae?

Comment: you could try to put them in { } array next to each other but that would be kinda pointless because data validation would not understand it as "extended range" so you have like two options: either have a big gap between them like 50+ columns (you can hide it so don't worry about visuals) or you can put each of those 3 array formulas into separate sheet and refer a whole row in data validation

Comment: I've trialled the latter and it seems to work well. I've set a new tab up called 'Formulae' and have amended your formula to =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF('390'!J9:J65="Livery", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Operators!$C$2:C, Operators!$C$2:C<>"")), IF('390'!J9:J65="Operator", TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Operators!$B$2:B, Operators!$B$2:B<>"")), )))) .....and this seems to be working perfectly so think I'll stick with this